# Is it possible to have a provider, which will provide a different implementation based on who is using(injecting) it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Specifically, I want to write a logging service in Angular, which would ideally have a setting for each of my services and factories like this:

```
{
   myService1: true,
   myService2: false,
   factory1: true, 
   ....
}
```

And based on it, it would decide if it should log or not.

You would use it the same way as $log, but you could easily configure it in one place for all your injectables.
So is it possible to somehow get a name of who is injecting my logging service?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in app.config() by creating app.provider()

something like:

```
app.provider('myLog', function() {
  //...your code
  });

app.config(function(myLogProvider) {
  myLogProvider.setOptions({
  //your config is here
    });
});
```

Comment: I know you can configure a provider, but that is not gonna give me what I need. I need to be able to dynamically get a name of who injected logging service.